# Does HTTP long polling support heartbeat message?

Tags: http, long-polling, cometd

I am using HTTP long polling for pushing server events to a client.

On the client side, I send a long polling request to the server and block there waiting for a event from the server.

On the server side, we used the cometd framework (I am on the client side, do not really know much about the server side).

The problem is, after sometime, the connection is broken and the client can not detect this, so it blocks there forever. We are trying to implement some kind of heartbeat message, which will be sent every N minutes to keep the connection active. But this does not seem to work.

My question is: does HTTP long polling support heartbeat messages? As far as I understand, HTTP long polling only allows the server to send one event and will close the connection immediately thereafter. The client must reconnect and send a new request in order to receive the next event. Is it possible that the server sends heartbeat messages every N minutes while still keep the connection open until a real server event happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CometD framework, then it takes care of notifying the application (both on client and on server) about when the connection is broken, and it does send heartbeat messages.

What you call "HTTP long polling" is just a normal HTTP request, so in itself does not support heartbeat messages.
You can use HTTP long polling requests to implement heartbeat messages, and this is what CometD does for you under the covers.

In CometD, the response to a HTTP long poll request may deliver multiple messages, and the connection will **not** be closed afterwards. The client will send another HTTP long poll request without the need to reconnect, possibly reusing the previous connection.

CometD offers to your application a higher level API that is independent from the transport, so you can use WebSocket rather than HTTP, which is way more efficient, without changing a single line in your application.

You need to use the CometD libraries both on client ([javascript](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_javascript) and [java](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_java_client)) and on [server](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_java_server), and everything will just work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the client is an embedded devices, it's coded in C++ raw sockets, we can not use CometD. Do you know how CometD send these heartbeat messages? Because based on your third paragraph, long polling is still one request corresponds to one response, these heartbeat messages should not be sent through this long polling connection, otherwise it's one request to multiple responses, it's HTTP streaming, not HTTP long polling then. Does CometD opens another connection for heartbeat messages? How can I configure CometD to send these heartbeat messages?

Comment: CometD uses a protocol called [Bayeux](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_bayeux) to transport messages, either using HTTP or using WebSocket. For each HTTP long poll response, CometD can send many Bayeux messages. It's not streaming, it's pure long poll. If you want to use CometD (and I really mean [this project](http://cometd.org)) on the server, with a C++ client (which CometD does not provide), then you have to implement a Bayeux protocol C++ client. [The company behind CometD](https://webtide.com) may [help you out](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_support) about this.